# Prepopulate a field using bookmarklet in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to autofill a field using prepopulate module and custom bookmarklet. The field's name is "field_source" and I want to populate it with the page's url. The existing code found in help.txt is

```
javascript:u=document.location.href;t=document.title;s=window.getSelection() void(window.open(%22http://example.com/node/add/article?edit[title]=%22+escape(t)+'&edit[body][und][0][value]='+escape(s)+'&edit[field_url][0][value]='+escape(u),'_blank','width=1024,height=500,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));
```

I don't know javascript so I have no idea where to modify.